# CFDocument displays wrong images

Tags: image, coldfusion, pdf-generation

I am using ColdFusion 9 to create a PDF containing multiple QR codes.

Images were successfully created before generating the PDF document. The images are different to each other but they have a similar file size and resolution.

Now I generate HTML for each of the previous generated images and put it into a PDF document. The path is correct – I checked it.

```
<cfset amount="6" />
<cfdocument
    format="pdf"
    unit="cm"
    marginTop="0.5"
    marginLeft="0.5"
    marginRight="0.5"
    marginBottom="0.5"
    pageType="A4"
    filename="#path##name#.pdf">
     <cfoutput>
        <cfloop from="1" to="#amount#" index="i">
            <cfset filename = "#name#_#i#" />
            <img src="file://#path#codes/#filename#.png" style="width: 3.58cm; margin: 0 0.2cm 0.5cm;">
            #path#codes/#filename#
        </cfloop>
    </cfoutput>
</cfdocument>
```

But there is one problem: Only the first image is displayed properly. Every other image is an identical copy of the first one. So I got 6 identical images in this PDF document.

Let me point out that the paths are right. It is not 6 times the same path.

[image: pdf example]

Some completely different images are displayed properly. I think Coldfusion has some problems with displaying nearly identical (file size, resolution) images.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: What happens if you use http links for the img src?

Comment: It will happen the same.

Comment: What happens if you output the filename variable right before the image?  Is it the same everytime?

Comment: If you take it out of the cfdocument and just display the HTML does it display correctly?  If you inspect each image, does the right filename and path come up correctly in HTML?  Are you sure that your pregenerated barcodes were created correctly and not just copies of each other?

Comment: The filename variable is the same when I print it out before the image. I inspected the HTML and everything is correct. The QR codes are created correctly and they arent just copies. They were generated with the Xzing Java library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem.

There is a problem in ColdFusion with CFDocument and PNG bar code images. I converted them to JPG and everything works as expected.

```
<cfset amount="6" />
<cfdocument
    format="pdf"
    unit="cm"
    pageType="A4"
    filename="#path##name#.pdf">
     <cfoutput>
        <cfloop from="1" to="#amount#" index="i">
            <cfset filename = "#name#_#i#" />
            <cfimage
                action="convert"
                destination="#path#codes/#filename#.jpg"
                source="#path#codes/#filename#.png" />
            <img src="file://#path#codes/#filename#.jpg" style="width: 3.58cm; margin: 0 0.2cm 0.5cm;">
        </cfloop>
    </cfoutput>
</cfdocument>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yep, I recall someone having a similar problem with Barbecue (over in the adobe forums). cfdocument did not seem to detect subtle differences between similar (but different) bar code images - leading to duplicates. That person ended up using .jpg's too. Out of curiosity, did you come across anything "official" confirming there is an issue with png's and not jpg's? I have only found an [open bug report](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3155607)

Comment: Okay. The guy that filed it mentioned something about an Adobe engineer suggesting it might be related to an issue fixed in 9.0.1. But nothing definitive. So I was still wondering if it really is a confirmed problem with cfdocument -=and=- if the issue is truly confined to png's *only*- or if jpg's may be subject to same problem eventually ie In other words does using jpg really fix the issue or only seem to. If anyone hears anything new, please post a comment

Comment: This problem still exists in Coldfusion 11, with the latest patches applied. Not sure about the new "2016" edition.
For me the resolution was simple... 
<cfimage format="jpg"  ....>   job done